# WordAPI ApiException caught: Not Found

Tags: java, api, maven, javafx

I'm following [this][1] documentation to connect to api, I want to build a JavaFX app that you can enter a word and it's retrieves it from api and I wanted to test the feature before displaying contents on GUI. Howerer I got this exception that the words is not found while I tested endpoint in their website and that word had definitions. I'm pretty new to using API perhaps I missed something that isn't shown in the documentation?
Here is my code:

```java
 public void testDetailsWords(String word,String detail) {
        //String word = "lovely";  // Word
        //String detail = "definitions";  // Detail
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        apiClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
        apiClient.setBasePath("https://www.wordsapi.com/");

        // configure authentications
        Authentication auth;

        auth = apiClient.getAuthentication("Default");
        ((ApiKeyAuth) auth).setApiKey(Apikey);

        try {
            WordsApi wordsApi = new WordsApi();
            DetailsResponse response = wordsApi.details(word, detail);
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            System.out.printf("ApiException caught: %s\n", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Here is my Controller code :

```java
  @FXML
    private void handleDefinitions(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
String word =definitionsfield.getText();
String detail= "definitions";


        apiCall.testDetailsWords(word,detail);
    }
```

I would be grateful for the help.
[1]: http://restunited.com/docs/6vc24wq3ojpq

Answer (score 1):

It's seems that tutorial that I tried following is very misleading which is very dissapoing, but I've learned my lesson now .
I decided to use Unirest to get request and it's worked perfectly.
If you stumble upon the link it's better not to follow that tutorial